# como llevar consultas (case) de sqlServer a eloquent de laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

hola mi pregunta es como poder llevar consultas del tipo (case) de sql server a eloquent de laravel por ejemplo:

en la siguiente consulta sql nos dice que se seleccione las columnas codigo liquidacion, tipo y leyes imsur de la tabla liquidaciones y que en una nueva columna con el nombre stado nos muestre (carga lista) si el valor de la columna leyes imsur es igual a SI caso contrario que muestre (carga no lista)

```
select cod_liquidacion,tipo,
CASE leyes_imsur
when 'SI' THEN 'carga lista'
else 'carga no lista'
end as stado,
from liquidaciones
```

estaba viendo algo sobre utilizacion de (raw) para este tipo de consultas pero no lo entendi muy bien asi que mi pregunta es como poder hacer ese tipo de consulta pero en laravel, gracias.

Answer (score 2):

Laravel, o más puntualmente Eloquent no incluye una forma «bonita» de manejar los CASE o condiciones de SQL, hay algunas formas de incluirlo, pero tal y como lo nombras, son con los formatos *raw*, más exactamente con DB::raw() que permite ejecutar dicha sentencia tal cual como la pones.

Algunas personas prefieren intentar usar Eloquent al máximo como en este ejemplo:

```
Liquidacion::select('cod_liquidacion', 'tipo', DB::raw(CASE leyes_imsur when 'SI' THEN 'carga lista' else 'carga no lista' end as stado));
```

Otro prefieren poner la sentencia en `selectRaw()`, y hay otras opciones un poco más particulares.

Puedes ver la documentación: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queries#raw-expressions

Answer (score 2):

Asumiendo que tengas un modelo Liquidacion que represente a la tabla representaciones
puedes proceder de este modo:

```
$data = Liquidacion::selectRaw("cod_liquidacion, 
                                tipo, 
                                CASE leyes_imsur
                                WHEN 'SI' THEN 'carga lista'
                                ELSE 'carga no lista' END AS stado")->get();
```

Lo único que debes tener en cuenta es el uso de las comillas simples y dobles, usa estas últimas para englobar toda tu selección y las sencillas para englobar aquellos textos de tu propia consulta; dentro del mismo `selectRaw()` mete a las primeras 2 columnas que deseas seleccionar